# 100 Random Circles

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

After I compiled the previous code it worked but now I cant get the circumference of the circles to change to a different color of whats inside the circle. Any suggestions.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Dimension d = getSize();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) 
        {                        
            Color color = new Color(generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255));
            g.setColor(color);

            int circleSize = generator.nextInt(d.width / 4);
            int x = generator.nextInt(d.width - circleSize);
            int y = generator.nextInt(d.height - circleSize);
            g.fillOval(x, y, circleSize, circleSize);

            color = new Color(generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255), generator.nextInt(255));
            g.setColor(color);              
            g.drawArc(x, y, circleSize, circleSize, 0, 360);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid pack if I had a certain size and nothing inside it.

Comment: It seems to run as it should here. Appropriate dimensions, lots of circles and a black background. The only thing that didn't compile was your second import, `javax.swing.JPanel*;`. I removed that line, and everything was ok. Did you modify the code you wrote here?

Comment: I have removed just that import line and tried it, nothing happened. So I also tried changing the pack and still nothing..I am at a loss for words right now.

Comment: wow nevermind...I fixed it I was forgetting to compile my changes...Just wasnt thinking clearly

Comment: I removed my answer then

Comment: @afsantos question about the circumference of the circles in order to change the color of the circumference I would use .. drawArc (int x, int y , int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)

Comment: @ZekeP Yes, just generate another color, and then use `g.drawArc(x, y, circleSize, circleSize, 0, 360)`.

Comment: @afsantos thank you I figured it out, your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (700,500));` right before packing the frame. Those two methods are meant to be used in conjunction. In addition move the adding of the `JPanel` to after the size is set, this improves code readability and makes more sense if you think about the order of the statements.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("CircleFrame");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

CircleFramePanel panel = new CircleFramePanel();

frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (700,500)); // add it here

frame.pack();

frame.getContentPane().add(panel);  

frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Given the fact that the panel that is been added to the frame has its preferred size set, this is pointless, in any case, you should allow the frame to size to the preferred size of its content as this will automatically included the border insets of the frame decoration...